# How to parse JSON data using Lua patterns?

Tags: json, nginx, lua, gsub, lua-patterns

I am integrating lua-module in nginx. I want to check parameter's value is empty or not. Whenever I use following code, I get true result against the JSON request

**Request**

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "username": "Ethen",
      "type": "PDF"
    }
  },
  "passport": {
    "user": "001"
  },
}
```

**Code**

```
local arg = ngx.req.get_body_data();
L="return "..arg:gsub('("[^"]-"):','[%1]=')
T=loadstring(L)()
ngx.print(T.data.user.username)
if T.data.user.username == "" then
    ngx.say("Empty username");
end
```

But when I use this request, I got error (attempt to call a nil value stack traceback)
**Request**

```
    {
    "reference"    : "567456314",
    "callback_url" : "http://www.example.com/",
    "verification_mode" : "any",

    "document"         : {
        "proof"           : "data:image/png;base64,iVBOR=“,
        "additional_proof": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0=",
        "supported_types" : ["id_card","driving_license","passport"], 
        "expiry_date"     : "",
        "document_number" : ""
    },

    "address"         : {
        "proof"            : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG=",
        "supported_types"  : ["id_card","bank_statement"],
        "name"             : "",
        "issue_date":""
    }
}
```

**Code**

```
local arg = ngx.req.get_body_data();
L="return "..arg:gsub('("[^"]-"):','[%1]=')
T=loadstring(L)()
ngx.print(T.document.proof)
if T.document.proof == "" then
    ngx.say("Empty proof");
end
```

What's the problem and solution??....Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? A string, an expected output, your solution and description what goes wrong.

Comment: In other words, you're trying to convert JSON to Lua script?  Try `L="return "..arg:gsub('%[','{'):gsub('%]','}'):gsub('("[^"]+")%s*:','[%1]=')`

Comment: in the first case output is as follows
{ "data": { "user": { "username": "", "type": "TYPE" } }, "passport": { "user": "uuid" }, }: true Empty username . 

Same as above it should say as Empty proof in second case...

Comment: What does that regex do that you have mentioned?

Comment: That worked for me..But there is problem...Every time a request is made an error comes into error.log file of nginx.

lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: content_by_lua(sp.com:79):26: attempt to call a nil value stack traceback:
coroutine 0: content_by_lua(sp.com:79): in function <content_by_lua(sp.com:79):1>, client: x.x.x.x, server: sp.com, request: "POST /store HTTP/1.1", host: “yes.com"...Whats the main problem ? @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: Replace `T=loadstring(L)()` with `T=loadstring(L) and loadstring(L)() or {document={}}`

Comment: Replaced as 
  local arg = ngx.req.get_body_data();
  L="return "..arg:gsub('%[','{'):gsub('%]','}'):gsub('("[^"]+")%s*:','[%1]=')
  T=loadstring(L) and loadstring(L)() or {document={}}
===>error in /var/log/nginx/error.log: 2019/09/17 17:24:07 [error] 10855#10855: *2 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: content_by_lua(sp.com:85):33: attempt to index field 'address' (a nil value) stack traceback:

Comment: If `T.address` is `nil` then you must not try to look inside it.  Replace `T.address.proof` with `T.address and T.address.proof or ""`

Comment: Please don't do that. Openresty has lua-cjson builtin, so you can just call `require('cjson').decode(ngx.req.get_body_data())` and you'll get a Lua table containing the JSON data like you want.